# X path expression using both substring-before and starts with used

Tags: xpath, substring, using, beforeupdate

I need xpath expression where i need to check whether the condition is true or not. I have one field with value (Student/Marks/Grade) = 7077634943*#*#*Test1.
first i need to find whether that field is having value like "*#*#*" and then i need to substring-before with '*#*#*' and then check the result starts with value '7' if condition satisfies then it should return true else false.

Please provide your valuable comments also let me know if you don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you require the substring, going by your requirements all you want to do is determine if the value contains ## and it starts with a number 7. If this is all you need the below xpath will work.

Note: untested as you have not posted any xml sample.

`/student/Marks/Grade[contains(. , '##') and starts-with(.,'7')]`